# Prove that $d(x,M)=\frac{|\langle f,x \rangle|}{||f||}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I want to show that for $E$ a normed space, $f\in E^*$ and $M=\{x\in E\,:\, f(x)=0\}$:

1. Write $M^\perp$
2. Show that $d(x,M)=\frac{|\langle f,x\rangle|}{||f||}$.

This is my attempt:
For the second part: We have that $f\in E^*$ and for $x\in E$ and $m\in M$
$$\
|\langle f,x-m|\rangle \leq ||f|| ||x-m|| \Rightarrow \frac{|\langle f,x\rangle|}{||f||} \leq ||x-m||.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{|\langle f,x\rangle|}{||f||} \leq \inf_{m\in M}||x-m|| =d(x,M).
$$
The second inequalyty is that I can't prove, I think that any corollary of Hanh-Banach could help me to prove that  $$d(x,M)\leq \frac{|\langle f,x\rangle|}{||f||} $$ Does anyone have any idea and could check my proof?

**Update**

I found the same question in this link [Orthogonality Relations Exercise, Brezis' Book Functional Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724154/orthogonality-relations-exercise-brezis-book-functional-analysis)

Comment: At the end of the first part how do you deduce $f=g$?