# Ex $1.17(3)$ in Brezis Functional Analysis

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, dual-spaces

I am working on the Exercise $1.17$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1724154).These are my attempt as followings:

It is clear that there exists a non-zero function $f\in E^*$. From equation $2$, we know that $\text{dist}(u,M)=\frac{|<f,u>|}{\left \| f \right \| }$. According to $1.3$, we know that $\||f|| = 1$, which implies that $\text{dist}(u,M) = |\int_{0}^{1}u(t)\,\mathrm{d}t|$. Suppose the infimum can be reached for some $u_0$, i.e., for such $u_0 \in E-M$, there exists a corresponding $v_0 \in M$ such that
$$\inf_{v\in M}\left \| u_0-v \right \|=\left \|u_0-v_0  \right \|.  $$

And
$$\text{dist}(u_0,M)=|\int_{0}^{1}u(t)\,\mathrm{d}t|, \text{i.e.},|\int_{0}^{1}u_0(t)-v_0(t)\,\mathrm{d}t|=\left \| u_0-v_0 \right \| =\max_{t\in[0,1]}|u_0(t)-v_0(t)|.$$ Since $u_0, v_0 \in E$, we have $(u_0 - v_0)(0) = 0$, which is obviously impossible.

Next, we prove: Since $u_0(t),v_0(t)$is continuous, suppose
$$\left \| u_0(t)-v_0(t)\right \| =(u_0-v_0)(t_0),$$
$\exists t_\delta\in(0,t_0) $
such that
$$\ (u_0-v_0)(t)\leq \frac{1}{2}\left \| u_0(t)-v_0(t)\right \|,\forall t\in[0,t_\delta)$$

Then
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}u_0(t)-v_0(t)\,\mathrm{d}t&=\int_{0}^{t_\delta}u_0(t)-v_0(t)\,\mathrm{d}t+\int_{t_\delta}^{1}u_0(t)-v_0(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&\leq(1-\frac{1}{2}t_\delta)\left \| u_0(t)-v_0(t)\right \|<\left \| u_0(t)-v_0(t)\right \| 
\end{align}
it contradicts.

Comment: This seems correct, although you should add absolute values in the last lines. By the way, you can use the commands `\left` and `\right` to make it so parentheses, vertical bars and other delimiters match the size of their content, like in the LHS of this simple example: $$\left|\int_0^1 g(t) \mathrm{d}t\right| \leq \int_0^1 |g(t)| \mathrm{d}t$$ You can also right-click other users' MathJax expressions and choose "Show Math as" -> "TeX Commands" to see how they wrote their code, sometimes it's quite helpful. Sorry if you already knew all of that. Have a good day otherwise!

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I'll pay more attention to posting questions in the future!